# Some comparison between Java package and C# namespace

Tags: java, c#, namespaces, package, programming-languages

From [Programming Language Pragmatics 4ed by Michael Scott](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~gxt29/teaching/underpl/Scott4eSupplement.pdf)

> C# follows Java’s lead in extracting header information automatically
>   from complete class deﬁnitions.

Then it continues to mention where namespaces in C# differ from packages in Java:

1. > Its module-level syntax, however, is based
   >   on the namespaces of C++, which allow a single ﬁle to contain
   >   fragments of multiple namespaces.

   Does Java allow a single file to contain fragments of multiple
   packages?
2. > There is also no notion of standard search
   >   path in C#: to build a complete program, **the programmer must provide
   >   the compiler with a complete list of all the ﬁles required.**

   How does a C# programmer  provide the compiler with a complete
   list of all the ﬁles required?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Java allow a single file to contain fragments of multiple packages?

If there is a package statement, it must be the first line of your Java source code. This means that the answer to your question is "no": you can have at most one package declaration per Java source file.

> How does a C# programmer must provide the compiler with a complete list of all the files required?

This applies only to building on the command line, because IDEs take care of this automatically. When you build your code on the command line with `csc.exe` you must provide a list of all files composing your module either by listing them one-by-one, e.g.

```
csc src\File1.cs src\File2.cs src\File3.cs
```

or by specifying a pattern:

```
csc src\*.cs
```